# Can JavaScript's Fetch be used to update param values in a Rails controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datatables

Using JavaScript, Rails, as well as the DataTables API to set up a reporting interface for tracking task activity. Right now, I'm trying to figure out how to update the client-facing data table with new data by wiring up the interface's existing date selection buttons (e.g., Today, Last 7 Days, Last 30 Days, etc.) using JavaScript to switch between different `time_range` param values in the Rails controller.

In the controller code, switching between these param values is meant to result in an update to a server-side query's `date_range` parameter. This parameter subsequently filters which data is returned by the server-side query by controlling what is specified in the db command's WHERE clause.

***My problem*** is that the fetch request I've set up in my JavaScript is evidently failing to have any influence on switching which param values are being passed into the control flow at the top of the controller's `index` method.

---

#### Edit

Here's what the network pane in dev tools shows after making clicks on the "Yesterday" and "Last 7 Days" date selection buttons. These clicks appear to be running successful fetch requests:

[image: Tracking Fetch requests in the Network activity tracker in DevTools]

One other thing I should point out here is that the data returned and viewable from the Network Tool's Preview is the *same* for my "Yesterday" fetch as it is for my "Last 7 Days" fetch. The whole point of making my fetch requests is that it retrieves a json data structure tailored to the date range selected in the interface via its interaction with the query written in the Rails controller.

Over there, using `puts` to output the value of my `@date_range` variable after the control-flow block (delimited this debugging aspect with dash-blocks), Rails console is reporting the problem exactly - that my client-side code *is not* updating the value of `@date_range` as expected, however, it *does* show a `Parameters` hash at the top noting visibility of updates to the value passed to `time_range`:

```
Started GET "/task_reporting?time_range=yesterday" for ::1 at 2019-09-17 10:01:21 -0400
Processing by TaskReportingController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"time_range"=>"yesterday", "task_reporting"=>{}}
  User Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
      ---------------------------------------------------------
      The value of @date_range is >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
      ---------------------------------------------------------
   (13.1ms)          SELECT tasks.id, tasks.name, users.name, DATE_FORMAT(MAX(kits.updated_at), '%a. %b %d, %Y'),
        COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE(kits.updated_at))), COUNT(DISTINCT(kits.id))
        FROM kits
        JOIN tasks ON tasks.id = kits.task_id JOIN users ON users.id = kits.user_id JOIN annotations ON annotations.kit_id = kits.id
        WHERE kits.updated_at >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        GROUP BY tasks.id, users.name

Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 15.7ms)


Started GET "/task_reporting?time_range=last_seven_days" for ::1 at 2019-09-17 10:02:29 -0400
Processing by TaskReportingController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"time_range"=>"last_seven_days", "task_reporting"=>{}}
  User Load (4.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
      ---------------------------------------------------------
      The value of @date_range is >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
      ---------------------------------------------------------
   (1.7ms)          SELECT tasks.id, tasks.name, users.name, DATE_FORMAT(MAX(kits.updated_at), '%a. %b %d, %Y'),
        COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE(kits.updated_at))), COUNT(DISTINCT(kits.id))
        FROM kits
        JOIN tasks ON tasks.id = kits.task_id JOIN users ON users.id = kits.user_id JOIN annotations ON annotations.kit_id = kits.id
        WHERE kits.updated_at >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        GROUP BY tasks.id, users.name

Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)
```

#### End edit

---

More info described in code comments...

My JavaScript (task_reporting.js.coffee) is called from the end of the view code for this tool:

#### Rails View (simplified)

index.html.haml:

```rb
-content_for :action_specific_js do
  != "task_reporting.init()"
```

#### JavaScript (jQuery + CoffeeScript)

```js
window.task_reporting = ( ->
    // Important: initializes DataTable, loading default, thirty-day date-range data
    init: () ->
          this.init_datepicker_button()
          this.init_daterange_buttons()
          $("#tasks_report").DataTable
              paging: false
              scrollY: "400px"
              scrollCollapse: true
              sAjaxSource: "/task_reporting"
              order: [[1, "asc"]]
    // Important: Believe the problem is here.
    // Method should send fetch request to server-side, altering query parameters in the controller
    render_table: (passed_time_range) ->
          query_params = "?time_range=#{passed_time_range}"
          console.log(query_params)

          fetch("/task_reporting#{query_params}",
              method: 'GET'
              headers:
                  "content-type": "application/json"
                  "Accept": "application/json"
              credentials: "same-origin"
          )
          .then (response) -> response.json()
          .then (data) ->
            console.log(data)
            $("#tasks_report").DataTable().clear().rows.add(data).draw
          .catch((e) -> console.error("Error:", e))

    // Not important: sets listener on date-range button (undeveloped)
    init_datepicker_button: ->
          dateRangeButton = $(".datepickerContainer > button#daterange")
          dateRangeButton.on "click", this.init_dropdown

    // Sets listeners on individual date range buttons, calling pass_time_range to set param value in fetch
    init_daterange_buttons: ->
          rangeItemButton = $(".range-item")
          rangeItemButton.on "click", this.pass_time_range

    init_dropdown: ->
          console.log "dropdown here"

    // Handles event on daterange buttons
    // Passes param value to render_table according to button's class name
    pass_time_range: (e) ->
          e.preventDefault()
          // console.log e
          clickedTimeRange = e.target.className
          if clickedTimeRange.includes "today"
              task_reporting.render_table("today")
          else if clickedTimeRange.includes "yesterday"
              task_reporting.render_table("yesterday")
          else if clickedTimeRange.includes "last_seven_days"
              task_reporting.render_table("last_seven_days")
          else if clickedTimeRange.includes "last_thirty_days"
              task_reporting.render_table("last_thirty_days")
          else if clickedTimeRange.includes "custom_range"
              task_reporting.render_table("custom_range")
)()
```

#### Rails Controller

```rb
class TaskReportingController < ApplicationController
  
  before_filter :authenticate
  
  def index
    
      # Checks param value and updates @date_range accordingly
      if params[:time_range] == "range_today"
        @date_range = '>= CURDATE()'
      elsif params[:time_range] == "range_yesterday"
        @date_range = '>= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)'
      elsif params[:time_range] == "range_last_seven_days"
        @date_range = '>= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)'
      else params[:time_range] == "range_last_thirty_days"
        @date_range = '>= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)'
      end
    
    # My fetch obviously fails to influence the :time_range param value
    # as the default thirty day range is always output here
    print <<-EOM
      ############
      The value of @date_range is #{@date_range}
      ############
    EOM

    # heredoc query
    query = <<-SQL
        SELECT tasks.name, users.name, DATE_FORMAT(MAX(kits.updated_at), '%a. %b %d, %Y'), 
        COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE(kits.updated_at))), COUNT(DISTINCT(kits.id)) 
        FROM kits
        JOIN tasks ON tasks.id = kits.task_id JOIN users ON users.id = kits.user_id JOIN annotations ON annotations.kit_id = kits.id
        WHERE kits.updated_at #{@date_range}
        GROUP BY tasks.id, users.name
      SQL
        
    query_result = Kit.connection.execute(query).to_a

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: {"aaData": query_result} }
    end
  end
end
```

Looking for some direction in where I'm going wrong. Would welcome any advice on whether using fetch like this is the correct way to go about updating table data from the client-side using the DataTables API.

Comment: Show the log when fetch does the ajax call, what's inside `params`? also check the browser's dev tools, the network tab should also give you info of the request.

Comment: Thanks, I'm relatively new at this (esp. with the Rails aspect) and hadn't yet considered looking at my request from the network console. While it's helpful I can see more explicit information about the request as I've coded it, I'm still not sure how to pass my query string parameters from my JS into the Rails controller. In any case, I've updated my post with a screenshot of the request as well as the Rails log output. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your param's value is "yesterday" or "last_seven_days" on your log, but your code checks against "range_yesterday" or "range_last_seven_days". That's why it's failing and falling back to the default range.

Do something like:

```
query_params = "?time_range=range_#{passed_time_range}"
```

or change your checks to compare agains "yesterday" instead of "range_yesterday"

Comment: Hahaha, yes that difference in the name-checking for the params value in my Rails controller was completely it. Have regrettably been floundering on this issue for the past three days after updating the values to pass into `query_params` without `range_` in my JS and overlooking making this same update in my Rails controller.

Comment: The fetch request is now working exactly as needed. Gratefully moving next to updating the actual table using DataTables. __*Thank you so much*__ for taking time to read into my problem and my code, and pointing out it's a simple difference in naming. ‍♂️

Have to figure out a dependable way to avoid making such mistakes in the future